# Add image to button without resizing

Tags: android

I added an image called "star" to a button and the picture appeared, but it made the button larger.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/latest_photoB"
android:layout_height="87dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#dcdcdc"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/star"
android:text="Latest Photos"
android:textSize="10dp"
android:textColor="#000000"  />
```

I tried many different ways, such as making it an `imagebutton`.

I tried `android:background = image`, but nothing worked. How can I add a picture, and keep it the same size?

Comment: you want to keep it the same size as what? if you set a background then set the height and width it should keep that size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to have an image background, do the following:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/latest_photoB"
    android:layout_height="87dp"
    android:layout_width="87dp"
    android:background="@drawable/star"
    android:text="Latest Photos"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"  />
```

If the button is supposed to be of fixed size, layout_weight is not required. Also, you hadn't defined `layout_weight` attribute. I have set it `87dp`. Change it as required.

Comment: layout_width = "87dp" didnt work - it changed the size of my button.

Comment: @DianeWener Is there a size that you like to assign to the button? You should use that size in place of `87dp`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for `android:setAdjustViewBounds = "false"`

Comment: i want the button to remain the same size, it got bigger once it displayed the image.

Answer (score 0):

The default background drawable for a button uses what is called a nine-patch. It will resize itself to the size of the content of the button. A button is a special TextView which can have drawables (compound drawables) attached to each of its 4 sides. The text and compound drawables make up the Button's content, which is why the button is resizing.

Compound drawables are an optimisation to the view hierarchy because it reduces the number of views for a very common scenario, but it sounds like you want an ImageView + a button, where the ImageView responds the same way as the button when you click on it?

In that case, wrap the button in a Layout with an ImageView inside it, and set your onClickListener on the layout rather than the button

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

And instead, define a specific size for your button:

```
android:layout_height="87dp"
android:layout_width="50dp"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Android Button will wrap the content(same as Image size) if you will not set the height and the width of the Button. Try this way

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/latest_photoB"
android:layout_height="87dp"
android:layout_width="87dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/star"
android:text="Latest Photos"
android:textSize="10dp"
android:textColor="#000000"  />
```